# Can I develope android app for bluetooth v2 and expand it to v4

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I want to develope an application on android for communicating with bluetooth devices. In this time I want to start with bluetooth v2.0 . but it is so important for me to know that is it possible to use the same application with bluetooth 4.0 (BLE) ??

Comment: You can use the Buletooth chat application demo that comes with the android sdk demos and then test compatibility

Comment: You will need to add different code for interacting with BLE devices, but it should be possible to have code for both cases in the same app.